# onResume() in android runtime error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to call onResume so that I can reload variables after they are changed from another fragment after I return.

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        check1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);

    }
```

Attached above is my onResume() code. CheckBox01 is in another fragment. However, on runtime I get an error and the application quits.

It is complaining

> Unable to resume Activity: android.app.supernotcalledException:
>   Fragment Tabmodes did not call through to super.Resume()

Where is my error?

Comment: More like *WHAT* is your error?

Comment: Are we expected to guess your crash stacktrace or you share it with us?

Comment: Add super.onResume() first thing in onResume.....

Answer (score 8):

You must call the super method when you override `onResume()`, as the error (cryptically) states:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    check1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`supernotcalledException` and `did not call through to super.Resume()` are telling what's the error!

You're missing the `super.onResume();` call when overriding the `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are required to call super.onResume. when overriding the initialize and teardown methods in android, you have to call the super version of the method or it won't work. super.onCreate, super.onResume, super.onDestroy, etc. i tend to start my init methods with the super call and end my teardown methods with it.